# Wall parallel to cieling/floor joists- is it load bearing?

Tags: joists, load-bearing, demolition

I have a wall on the first floor I'd like to remove that runs parallel to my cieling/floor joists. This is my first demolition project in the house and I'd love some insight prior to contacting a structural engineer so I know what I'm getting into and have baseline knowledge of what to expect.

Some info about the house in general:

1. It is a 2 story house with a basement (concrete block foundation), first floor, second floor and an an attic (the roof has no additional supports anywhere on the attic floor).
2. The house runs 20 feet in width with a central load bearing wall running perpendicular to the joists along the full length of the house. The same thing is found in the second floor. Metal posts can be found supporting this load in the basement into the foundation.

I removed the drywall on one side of the wall in question to get a better idea of what was going on and the pictures (1 & 2) are attached below. Here's a brief description of the findings:

1. The blue lines show the original studs that were in place (seems like 2/3s of the wall used to be opened up but there was no header or stud pack to support the top of this?

2)The right side of the door's frame doesnt have a king stud, just a pair of jack studs.

3. The red lines show the joists running parallel, 16in apart. The wall is not directly underneath any joists. There is one joist 10in in front, and another joist 6in behind this wall. However there is a wall on the second floor that is somewhat above this wall (but there is no direct wood to wood connection as there is a clear space between this wall and the second floor wall--See pictures 3 & 4 of the cieling space above the wall in question)
4. The green line all the way to the left of the photo is definitely the central load bearing wall running the full length of the house.

I don't see any direct load transfer from the second floor to this wall, so I wanted to get input to see if this is indeed not a load bearing wall. And if it isn't load bearing, does that typically mean this wall can just be removed without any additional support? Or would the 2 joists near this wall ned to be sistered for extra support.

Thanks!

[image: layout]
[image: annotated layour]
[image: cieling space of joist 10in in front]
[image: cieling space of joist 6in behind]

Comment: That does not look like an interior door, more like an outside door.  Is this an outside wall or was it an outside wall at one point?  An inside wall parallel to joists is not load bearing, but this changes with outside walls.  Or a wall going into a garage.

Comment: That looks like an exterior door- what's on theother side of the wall?  And the studs look wider than 2 by 4s - are they 2 by 6s or 2 by 8s, or is it just an illusion?

Comment: @crip659 It is an interior door as this room is in the middle of the house and there are 2 more room after this one. I would like to knock this wall down to combine this room and the room after it (leaving one more room at the very end which would be on the xterior end of the house). An exterior wall touching this room is on the right side of the wall.

Comment: @Mark as for the studs, the original studs as outlined in blue are 2x4s and had lather and plaster on it. However the new-ish looking studs that aren't outlined is a 2x3 sitting ontop of a 2x4 (it seems like the 2nd owner of the house did this to match the dimension of the original 2x4s in blue plus the lather/plaster boards before putting new drywall ontop of everything)

Comment: If an inside wall with a fancy door, have fun with the sledge hammer.  It was the door that led to some concern.